# DataGridView Scroll show columns over others

Tags: vb.net, reflection, datagridview, cells, doublebuffered

I have a datagridview, and when i use scrollbar the columns shown over the others, like this image:
[image: here]

i have tried `DoubleBuffered` like that:

1- i created a module named "DoubleBuffer.vb"

2- i add that code in it:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module DoubleBuffer
    Public Sub DoubleBuffered(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal setting As Boolean)
        Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
        Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, Nothing)
    End Sub
End Module
```

3- i call that module in `Load Event`:

```
DoubleBuffer.DoubleBuffered(DataGridView1, True)
```

but it give me BLACK Cells

so, what is the problem i faced here?

Comment: Is this from a customised DataGridView control? That is, is the control you use a custom control that inherits from `DataGridView`? The only time I have seen things like this is when the control is customised and the `_paint` and/or `_draw` events are incorrectly implemented or something is missing from them

Comment: i only customized the rows align and the cells colors with no events, just from properties.